# setting state with the data coming from graphql in react

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am making a query in graphql inside return and things seems to be working fine as I can see the data .
However the requirement is that I want that data to be stored in my state instead of simply rendering the items .

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.broadcasters();
     );
broadcasters =()=>{
    <Query query={BROADCASTERS_QUERY}>

            {
                ({loading,error,data}) =>{

                    if(error) console.log(error)
                    console.log("graphql data is ",data);
                    debugger
              }
            }

           </Query>

  }
```

On doing above I got this error .
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
My concern is that how can we store the coming data in state .

Comment: use HOC, your data will be in props

Comment: can you throw more light on this ?

Comment: [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/recompose)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to write an HOC which renders you component and passes the value as props

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
     const {loading,error,data} = this.props;
     //
  }

}
export default (props) => {
   <Query query={BROADCASTERS_QUERY}>
        {
             (data) =>{
                   return <MyComponent {...props} {...data}/>
              }
         }
    </Query>
}
```